# Can't build a project package using boost/iostream from bazel

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, bazel

I am using https://github.com/nelhage/rules_boost in a bazel project, everything is working fine except when I try to use boost/iostream. 
The problem occurs on windows 10, and not on linux. boost/iostream depends on zlib and the file that is downloaded is https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: .../external/net_zlib_zlib/BUILD.bazel:6:1: in cc_library rule @net_zlib_zlib//:zlib: Expected action_config for 'preprocess-assemble' to be configured
ERROR: Analysis of target '.../storage:storage' failed; build abo
```

rted: Analysis of target '@net_zlib_zlib//:zlib' failed; build aborted

This is the BUILD file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "storage",
    srcs = [
      "blobstore.cc",
      "blobstore.h",
    ],
    hdrs = [
      "blobstore.h",
    ],
    deps = [
      "@boost//:iostreams",
    ],
    defines = ["BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB"],
)
```

Does anyone have idea what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately a bug in our MSVC crosstool. What needs to be done is to add the missing `action_config` and make sure other compilation flags are compatible. Would you mind creating a [github issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new)?